# How can I define new generic list of objects in Swift?

Tags: list, generics, swift, collections, initialization

I can easy define new collection with some object type in C#, using the next code:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

// in some other method
var listPesrons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 0, Name = "Oleg" },
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Lena" }
};
```

What is the analog for Swift programming language for the code list above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close equivalent would be:

```
public class Person {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String

    public init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

var listPersons = [
    Person(id: 0, name: "Oleg"),
    Person(id: 1, name: "Lena")
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a struct, the code is very similar:

```
public struct Person {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String
}

// persons will be an Swift Array 
let persons = [
    Person(id: 0, name: "Oleg"),
    Person(id: 1, name: "Lena"),
]
```

If you wanted a class instead of a struct (and generally, you might want to think about a struct first, and a class only if you really need the features classes bring) then you'll also need an initializer:

```
public class Person {
    public var id: Int
    public var name: String

    public init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```